# Can PAM be used to authenticate non-OS users?

Tags: authentication, pam

I have a webapp (JupyterHub served from Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).  I'd like to have users authenticate to it with a username/password pair. These users will not typically have local OS user accounts.  Is it possible to use PAM to authenticate users against, say, a local database or password file instead of local OS accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PAM stands for "Pluggable Authentication Modules". The whole idea is that the platform is modular allowing you to source your users and authentication systems from anywhere necessary. As you're using Ubuntu, you should be able to find a whole [host of modules](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpam&searchon=names&suite=artful&section=all) that should cover what you're after, for example libpam-mysql (which provides pam_mysql.so).  There are plenty of examples as well as references to the module's home page.